# Uso de variáveis globais e variáveis de classe no Delphi

Tags: delphi, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Eu tenho algumas dúvidas quanto ao uso de variáveis globais e variáveis de classe usando `class var` no Delphi.

Declarando variáveis de classe com `class var`.

```delphi
unit Unit1;

interface

type
  TClass = class
  public
    class var _Object: TObjectList<Integer>
  end;

implementation
end.
```

Declarando variáveis globais

```delphi
unit Unit1;

interface

var
  _Object: TObjectList<Integer>

implementation
end.
```

## Pergunta:

Como o compilador aloca memória para essas declarações?
Qual forma de uso é a mais indicada para ser utilizada?

Comment: Depende da intenção.  Se é uma variável de suporte à classe ou a todas as instâncias dessa classe (ou subclasses), deve ser uma `class var`.  Se tiver interesse fora do âmbito da classe e esse interesse for partilhado e único, talvez deva ser uma `var` global, embora prefira sempre que possível usar um campo de um objecto singleton, para agrupar campos/propriedades de forma lógica.  E esse objecto sim estar numa variável global ou ser acessível/instanciável através de outro objecto global.

Comment: Em geral acho que é melhor minimizar o uso de variáveis globais e tender a colocar as outras variáveis nas classes.

Answer (score 5):

O processo de alocação de memória de uma variável de classe usando o `class var` é o mesmo que uma variável global.

A unica diferença é que a variável declarada como `class var` vai ter um escopo de classe.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986202/use-of-variables-global-and-variables-of-class-in-delphi

Comment: Você pode marcar sua própria resposta como aceita.

Answer (score 3):

Após a separação da CodeGear da Borland a equipe responsável pelo Delphi procurou modernizar a linguagem. Neste sentido, adicionou construções de linguagem que visam permitir melhores práticas de programação, notadamente dando à aplicação um modelo mais orientado a objetos.

As variáveis de classe públicas e globais são relativamente similares, no sentido de que terão apenas uma instância, mas as variáveis de classe têm a vantagem de estar definidas dentro do escopo da classe, o que evita eventuais colisões de nomes em diferentes `units` ou mesmo dentro da mesma `unit`.

Por este último motivo eu recomendo o uso de variáveis de classe.

Answer (score 2):

Em qualquer ambiente de desenvolvimento que forneça facilidades de escopo para as variáveis de forma que você possa criar membros na Classe (Java, Delphi, C#, etc.) use sempre estas funcionalidades em vez de variáveis globais ou de classe pois estas variáveis vão criar acoplamento excessivo no seu código dificultando a manutenção. O Design Pattern **Singleton** permite que se crie algo melhor que simplesmente usar Variáveis globais mas também deve ser evitado.

Answer (score 1):

Só para incrementar o que já foi falado.

Eu já vi duas variáveis globais em unit´s diferentes mas com o mesmo nome. Eram do tipo de uma classe. Ao instanciá-la na unit1, era instanciada a da unit2. Na hora de destruir, era então destruida a da unit1. Resultado: "Access Violation".

Como era praticamente impossível mudar a cultura do pessoal em relação ao var Global, eu instrui a declararem dentro do escopo de implementation na unit, em vez da interface. Isso fez ela não ficar visível para as outras units, resolvendo temporariamente o problema.

Answer (score 1):

A linguagem de programação por traz do Delphi é o Object Pascal cuja origem está no Pascal estruturado, isto é, não orientado a objeto. Por este motivo existe na sintaxe suporte a variáveis globais. Mas num programa Orientado a Objetos não é uma boa prática usar variáveis globais.

Se mesmo assim desejar usar variáveis globais tenha em mente as seguintes regras:

1- Variáveis globais não estão relacionadas a nenhuma classe.
2- Elas são declaradas na seção INTERFACE da unit e quando usadas é boa prática seguir a sintaxe UnitNome.VariavelNome. Exemplo: UnitPessoa.QtdePopulacao := 1234;
3- Elas podem ser referidas em todas os códigos de programas, procedure, function e métodos que usam a unit na qual a variável está definida;
4- Elas podem ser inicializadas ou finalizadas nas seções INITIALIZATION E FINALIZATION da unit na qual está declarada.

Variáveis estáticas das classes "Class Var" seguem as seguintes regras:

1- São declaradas na definição da classe e seu valor é compartilhado por todas as instâncias da classe. 
2- Métodos de classe podem fazer referência a elas;

Minha sugestão final:

1- Use variável global quando ela for armazenar informações relacionadas a Unit na qual está declarada, e não específicas de uma determinada classe desta unit;
2- Nos demais casos, use variável de classe que é mais elegante, mais elucidativa, e segue o que é definido como boa prática de OO.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você declara uma variável no **VAR** na unit esta variável é estática e fica visível em qualquer local que importar a unit em questão.

Resumindo: Se unit1 tiver uma variável **varDaUnit1** e unit2 uses unit1, unit2 pode acessar varDaUnit1 como se ela fizesse parte de unit2. Qualquer alteração em seu valor será refletido para outras units que utilizam unit1.

Ao declarar uma variável no **public** da classe ela é uma variável dinâmica, que é criada e destruída junto com a classe. A acesso a variáveis no public é via classe, por exemplo:

```
classe1.varDaClasseDecalradaNoPublic;
```

Quando trabalhava com Delphi a empresa onde eu trabalhava traçou um conjunto de regras quanto ao uso do var, desencorajando seu uso. A única situação onde vejo que o uso do var seja plausível seria caso precise de uma variável global compartilhada em várias telas do sistema, ex.: Usuário logado.